# Ошибка при подсчете времени: "Required argument 'month' (pos 2) not found"

Tags: python, python-3.x

Ввожу `date_1 = 2016-10-12`, чтобы потом от него отнять 1 день и получить дату 2016-10-11. Почему код выдает ошибку `Required argument 'month' (pos 2) not found`?

```
import datetime 
import time

date_1 = 2016-10-12
ds = datetime.date(date_1)
delta = datetime.timedelta(days=1) # дельта в 1 день
now_date = ds - delta
print(now_date)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что когда вы пишите 2016-10-12, интерпретатор думает, что это "2016 минус 10 минус 12". Он производить эти вычисления, и получает число 1994.  А datetime.date требует, чтобы ему передали три отдельных числа - год, месяц, день. Если он получает только одно число, то он воспринимает это как год, а вот месяца он уже не находит, о чём и пишет в тексте ошибки.

Впрочем, это можно сделать почти так, как вы пытались, если использовать синтаксис распаковки:

```
date_1 = 2016, 10, 12
ds = datetime.date(*date_1)
```

Comment: если дата ввиде строки задана: `datestr = "2016-10-12"`, то `d = DT.datetime.strptime(datestr, '%Y-%m-%d').date()`